# No Sound from speakers and Headphones on Ubuntu 16.04 dell

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, speakers

I could not hear any sound from my laptop either from the speakers or from the ear phones.

[image: Following is the image of my sound settings]

I tried many things from the internet. but no luck.
While I am booting the system for the first system there was audio of Ubuntu that played, So I can confirm that speakers are working.
Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

Edit1:
Result of `pactl info`

```
Server String: unix:/run/user/1001/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 30
Server Protocol Version: 30
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 13
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: pradeep
Host Name: pradeep-Vostro-15-3568
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 8.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: 69fe:8c4c
```

Edit2:
 Result of `sudo lsof /dev/snd/*`

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Comment: Would you open a terminal and execute the command `pactl info`, and paste the results of that operation into your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have updated. Please help.

Comment: Thanks - I'd also like you to run `lsof /dev/snd/*`

Comment: Is pulseaudio even running?  Can you check the output of `ps -aux | grep -i pulse` and `pulseaudio --start`